# Send/receive SMS (text messages) and place/receive calls from an iPad

Tags: ipad, cellular-data

I'm looking for a solution to receive/place calls and SMS over the cellular network. 
For now, my best solution would be Skype, but i can't receive SMS with it. Is there an equivalent ?

Thanks.

Edit: it might be important : I'm in France, not in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Google Hangouts would do it. You'd have to get a Google account, and a Google Voice number, and then you can send/receive calls and texts with it.

If you had an iPhone i think you could also use the iPad to place/receive calls using the iPhone cell connection.  I don't think this is what you mean though

Comment: It seems like Google Voice is only available in the US (or at least the Google Voice Number is), am I right ?

Comment: I'm in the U.S. and I can not view it as outside of US people view it.

Comment: @Rogue, you probably could use a proxy server to set it up...

Comment: I did, to test it. I Got an US Phone number, it works but my french friends pay a lot more when they Call / text us Phone numbers

Comment: @Rogue the cost we can't help :)  are most or all of your friends on smartphones? Does something like Line/WhatsApp/Viber/etc make sense? Google hangouts itself has messaging also

Comment: I don't mind paying, but i do mind making my friends/family pay a lot ! Theses messaging app do make sense, but i'd need to have a regular phone number for pro contacts

Comment: @Rogue i agree with all you said :) maybe split, free apps with family, but a number just in case for outside contacts  only you can say if that works

Answer (score 1):

There are many free and paid services out there that let you send and/or receive SMS messages via your web browser; some of them such as [Skebby](http://www.skebby.com/sms-bulk-solutions/web-sms-send-receive-text-messaging-via-pc/) also have mobile apps available. You'd certainly have to do your research to find out which ones were reputable, though (and I make no such claim either way for Skebby, which I've never used... was just one of the first ones I found.)